# How to simplify this js?

Tags: javascript, simplify

I know that the solution is overly stupid but I do not find it: /
I'm looking to simplify this js code.

but I'm especially looking to understand so if you have a link to learn simplification.

I start the JS so do not judge me too much ;)

Thanks in advance.

Code Js :

```
$('#img1, #menu1').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu1').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img1').toggleClass("activeImg"); 
});

$('#img2, #menu2').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu2').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img2').toggleClass("activeImg"); 
});
$('#img3, #menu3').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu3').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img3').toggleClass("activeImg");  
});
$('#img4, #menu4').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu4').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img4').toggleClass("activeImg"); 
});
$('#img5, #menu5').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu5').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img5').toggleClass("activeImg");  
});
```

code HTML :

```
 <ul>               
    <li id="menu1">Module Accueil</li>
    <li id="menu2">Module Produit</li>
    <li id="menu3">Module Diaporama</li>
    <li id="menu4">Module Article</li>
    <li id="menu5">Module Contact</li>
</ul>
<img id="img1" src="/themes/courant/images/image1">
<img id="img2" src="/themes/courant/images/image2">
<img id="img3" src="/themes/courant/images/image3">
<img id="img4" src="/themes/courant/images/image4">
<img id="img5" src="/themes/courant/images/image5">
```

Comment: You're not on the right site for ask this. Go on code review section

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From a glance, I assume you can convert all that JS to CSS `:hover`..

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
$('ul li[id^=]').hover( function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass("activeMenu");
});
$('img[id^="img"]').hover( function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass("activeImg");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a common function as below to reduce duplicate code and have a common function to do the logic.

```js
function onHoverCall(selector1,selector2,selector3){
  $(selector).hover(
      function() {
          $(selector2).toggleClass("activeMenu");//you can change these as well
          $(selector3).toggleClass("activeImg"); 
  });
}
/*$('#img1, #menu1').hover(
    function() {
        $('#menu1').toggleClass("activeMenu");
        $('#img1').toggleClass("activeImg"); 
});*/
onHoverCall('#img1, #menu1','#menu1','#img1');
```

```html
   <li id="menu1">Module Accueil</li>
    <li id="menu2">Module Produit</li>
    <li id="menu3">Module Diaporama</li>
    <li id="menu4">Module Article</li>
    <li id="menu5">Module Contact</li>
</ul>
<img id="img1" src="/themes/courant/images/image1">
<img id="img2" src="/themes/courant/images/image2">
<img id="img3" src="/themes/courant/images/image3">
<img id="img4" src="/themes/courant/images/image4">
<img id="img5" src="/themes/courant/images/image5">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but i have this:  it's possible to simplify too ?                                     
onHoverCall('#img1, #menu1','#menu1','#img1');
onHoverCall('#img2, #menu2','#menu2','#img2');
onHoverCall('#img3, #menu3','#menu3','#img3');
onHoverCall('#img4, #menu4','#menu4','#img4');
onHoverCall('#img5, #menu5','#menu5','#img5');

Comment: you can have those id's in a variable and use them everywhere